# Silverlight Binding - CommandParameter to Parent (help remove an x:Name)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-7, command

Any idea how I can bind to the listbox and not use an x:Name for the code below? I'm using the xname at ElementName=myList

```
<ListBox x:Name="myList" Grid.Row="1" Height="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchedItemContainerStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent">
    <wi:Interaction.Triggers>
        <wi:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <wi:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ViewModel.Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myList}" />
        </wi:EventTrigger>
    </wi:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I really don't want to have to define a name for my control everytime I use the InvokeCommandAction.  Note: wi is Windows Interactivity for SL4/WP7.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try binding to the "SelectedItem" instead and remove the need to pass a CommandParameter altogether. Don't forget the Mode=TwoWay. Add a "SelectedListItem" INotifyPropertyChanged getter/setter in you ViewModel and bind to that property.

```
<ListBox SelectedItem={Binding SelectedListItem, Mode=TwoWay} Grid.Row="1" Height="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchedItemContainerStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent">
    <wi:Interaction.Triggers>
        <wi:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <wi:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ViewModel.Command}" />
        </wi:EventTrigger>
    </wi:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This will work, but it's a little more code than I care to have.  Was hoping for a way to say CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName={RelativeSource=Parent}".

Comment: @John - `RelativeSource.FindAncestor` is not supported in Silverlight 4. Yes it's a bummer, but such are the ways of a compact framework. vidalsasoon's answer hits the spot and will make your code more maintainable for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's actually possible, so while I doubt, and wait for others to answer, I would recommend a different approach.

You can use attached behaviours to do this, which is a simple and neat approach, giving a lot more clean code.

I've [written about it](http://windcape.posterous.com/command-extensions-for-the-silverlight-toolki) on [my blog](http://windcape.posterous.com/), and published a framework for it, that's [available on NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ToolkitExtensions).

What you need for your `ListBox` is the `SelectorExtension`. If you just want the code, look no futher than here: [SelectorExtension.cs](https://bitbucket.org/Windcape/toolkitextensions/src/bfc41cbb41b6/SelectorExtension.cs). (The source is MIT licensed)

This means you can simply change your code to the following:

```
<ListBox ext:SelectorExtension.Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ViewModel.Command}"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Height="Auto"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchedItemContainerStyle}"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         Background="Transparent">
    ...
```

where `ext` being `xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:ToolkitExtensions;clr-assembly=ToolkitExtensions"`